# assembly code of the c function

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to understand the assembly code of the C function. I could not understand why `andl -16` is done at the main. Is it for allocating space for the local variables. If so why `subl 32` is done for main.

I could not understand the disassembly of the `func1`. As read the stack grows from higher order address to low order address for 8086 processors. So here why is the access on positive side of the ebp(for parameters offset) and why not in the negative side of ebp. The local variables inside the func1 is 3 + return address + saved registers - So it has to be 20, but why is it 24? (`subl $24,esp`)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int a, int b){
 int res = 0;
 res = a + b;
 return res;
}
int func1(int a){
 int s1,s2,s3;
 s1 = add(a,a);
 s2 = add(s1,a);
 s3 = add(s1,s2);
 return s3;
}
int main(){
 int a,b;
 a = 1;b = 2;
 b = func1(a);
 printf("\n a : %d b : %d \n",a,b);
 return 0;
}
```

assembly code :

```
       .file   "sample.c"
        .text
.globl add
        .type   add, @function
add:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $16, %esp
        movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
        movl    12(%ebp), %eax
        movl    8(%ebp), %edx
        leal    (%edx,%eax), %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        leave
        ret
        .size   add, .-add
.globl func1
        .type   func1, @function
func1:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $24, %esp
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    add
        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    add
        movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)
        movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
                                      call    add
        movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
        movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
        leave
        ret
        .size   func1, .-func1
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "\n a : %d b : %d \n"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        andl    $-16, %esp
        subl    $32, %esp
        movl    $1, 28(%esp)
        movl    $2, 24(%esp)
        movl    28(%esp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    func1
        movl    %eax, 24(%esp)
        movl    $.LC0, %eax
        movl    24(%esp), %edx
        movl    %edx, 8(%esp)
        movl    28(%esp), %edx
        movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `andl $-16, %esp` aligns the stack pointer to a multiple of 16 bytes, by clearing the low four bits.

The only places where positive offsets are used with `(%ebp)` are parameter accesses.

You did not state what your target platform is or what switches you used to compile with. The assembly code shows some Ubuntu identifier has been inserted, but I am not familiar with the ABI it uses, beyond that it is probably similar to ABIs generally used with the Intel x86 architecture. So I am going to guess that the ABI requires 8-byte alignment at routine calls, and so the compiler makes the stack frame of `func1` 24 bytes instead of 20 so that 8-byte alignment is maintained.

I will further guess that the compiler aligned the stack to 16 bytes at the start of `main` as a sort of “preference” in the compiler, in case it uses SSE instructions that prefer 16-byte alignment, or other operations that prefer 16-byte alignment.

So, we have:

In `main`, the `andl $-16, %esp` aligns the stack to a multiple of 16 bytes as a compiler preference. Inside `main`, `28(%esp)` and `24(%esp)` refer to temporary values the compiler saves on the stack, while `8(%esp)`, `4(%esp)`, and `(%esp)` are used to pass parameters to `func1` and `printf`. We see from the fact that the assembly code calls `printf` but it is commented out in your code that you have pasted C source code that is different from the C source code used to generate the assembly code: This is **not** the correct assembly code generated from the C source code.

In `func1`, 24 bytes are allocated on the stack instead of 20 to maintain 8-byte alignment. Inside `func1`, parameters are accessed through `8(%ebp)` and `4(%ebp)`. Locations from `-12(%ebp)` to `-4(%ebp)` are used to hold values of your variables. `4(%esp)` and `(%esp)` are used to pass parameters to `add`.

Here is the stack frame of `func1`:

```
    - 4(%ebp) = 20(%esp): s1.
    - 8(%ebp) = 16(%esp): s2.
    -12(%ebp) = 12(%esp): s3.
    -16(%ebp) =  8(%esp): Unused padding.
    -20(%ebp) =  4(%esp): Passes second parameter of add.
    -24(%ebp) =  0(%esp): Passes first parameter of add.
```

Comment: This quote from the gcc manual may be helpful: -mpreferred-stack-boundary=num : Attempt to keep the stack boundary aligned to a 2 raised to num  byte boundary.  If -mpreferred-stack-boundary is not specified, the default is 4 (16 bytes or 128 bits).

Comment: Thanks for expalining the 8 byte alignment. My doubt is in add - > 1(local variable) + return address => 2 * 8 = 16 which holds correct. But in func1 -> 3(local variables) + return address = > 4 * 8 = 32 should be there . why is it 24. why in the main subl 32 is done for the base pointer. I'm a bit confused with the calculations made.

Comment: @Angus: In calculating the `func1` size, why do you multiply by 8? In this 32-bit architecture, the `int` objects in `func1` and address are each four bytes. `func1` uses four bytes for s1, four bytes for s2, four bytes for s3, eight bytes two pass two parameters to `add`, and four more bytes to pad for alignment. That is 24 bytes.

Comment: Thanks eric. I understoog now.

Comment: @eric : In main , I still could not understand why do we do andl -16,ebp and then subl $32,ebp . We have allocated 16 bytes for the local variables in main by doing andl -16,ebp . Then why again the subl 32,ebp is done.

Comment: @Angus: The low four bits of `%esp` have some value from zero to 15. The `andl $-16, %esp` clears those bits, reducing `%esp` to a multiple of 16. If `%esp` was already a multiple of 16, it does not change. Because you do not know in advance how much `%esp` will be reduced, you cannot count on any of those bytes for a stack frame. They are only for padding and remain unused. So you must subtract 32 from `%esp` to get the bytes you need.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest working through this with the output of `objdump -S` which will give you interlisting with the C source.